# is OAuth2 Authorization server supported by Spring WebFlux?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

is OAuth2 Authorization server supported by Spring WebFlux? I mean is it possible to develop a reactive OAuth2 Authorization server in Spring? if no, when it will be added to the framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think no, Authorization server is out of their roadmap. Starting from november the 13th every class in spring security which worked with Authorization server features become deprecated.

[Spring Security OAuth 2.0 Roadmap Update](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/14/spring-security-oauth-2-0-roadmap-update#no-authorization-server-support) (here the answer on you question)

Comment: from Spring blog : UPDATE: We’d like to thank everyone for your feedback on the decision to not support Authorization Server. Due to this feedback and some internal discussions, we are taking another look at this decision. We’ll notify the community on any progress.

Answer (score 1):

@mhrsalehi, please checkout my repo. I added an implementation of old  OAuth2 Authorization server for webflux. Currently only support `/oauth/token` if you want support for any other endpoints please submit a ticket or PR.

Github: [spring-reactive-authorization-server](https://github.com/VuDo98/spring-reactive-authorization-server)